# How to solve ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables?

Tags: oracle, dblink

I have created a DB link and I created a local synonym to the remote table. I also created a local view that selects data from the synonym. A blob column has been added to the remote table and I am unable to select it locally.

This is how my code looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW LOCAL_USER.VIEW AS (

SELECT
WHATEVER,
BINARY_CONTENT
FROM LOCAL_USER.LOCAL_TABLE

UNION  ALL 

SELECT
WHATEVER,
BINARY_CONTENT
FROM  LOCAL_USER.SYNONYM
);
```

and this is the error:

```
ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
```

I looked it up online, but the proposed solutions would not work for me cause I am using a synonym, that needs to be up to date with the remote table at all time.

Does anyone have an idea of what can be done about it?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @pmdba  oracle/database:12.2.0.1-ee

Comment: Both databases?

Comment: @pmdba yes. At the moment I test this locally so the remote db is also on my machine.

Comment: Does just the remote query, without the union, work? What about using the remote table name without the synonym?

Comment: If I only remove the BINARY_CONTENT from the above query it works. 
direct selects from db link works also. making any kind of view or synonym that includes the binary content does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adlob/working-with-LOBs.html#GUID-BA662EA5-4955-4582-B12E-3312FE4B1D6A), this usage of LOB is not supported.

> Oracle Database has limited support for remote LOBs and ORA-22992
> errors can occur when remote LOBs are used in ways that are not
> supported.

And creating views with remote LOBs are not on the list of supported operations as per the documentation above.

On Oracle support I found a document [796282.1](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/796282_1.html) for older version of database (12.1) with workaround, but this workaround seems very limited as it consist of converting CLOB/BLOB into VARCHAR2/RAW via support function and then accessing it remotely. This of course adds to limitation for VARCHAR2 at 4000 bytes and for RAW at 2000 bytes, which can be quite limiting.

Comment: This does also not work. I even tried to select the binary content directly from the db link in the subselect. Selecting directly works if it is not part of the view's create statement.