# "ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables "

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I have a query in oracle 19 which works fine:

```
select a.x,
       b.y
from tab1@dblink a
     join tab2@dblink b
     on a.x = b.y
```

But when I create a view from this query, I have the error - "ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables".

Columns x and y are varchar2 not lobs.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1
(
x VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
x2 CLOB,
x3 VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
),
CREATE TABLE tab2
(
y VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
y2 CLOB,
y3 VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
)
```

Do you have any idea why I have this error?

I want to know why query works fine and view doesn't.

Comment: That action is not supported - Documentation ( https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adlob/working-with-LOBs.html#GUID-BA662EA5-4955-4582-B12E-3312FE4B1D6A ) . Read the answer from ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62892515/how-to-solve-ora-22992-cannot-use-lob-locators-selected-from-remote-tables ). Regards...

Comment: But columns x and y are not lobs.

Comment: Can you add the two DDL `Create Table ..` statements to get a reproducible scenario?

Comment: I added two DDL.

Comment: Now try the same thing with tables that does not have any LOBs. That should work fine. When you are reaching for a table over a dblink and that table has a LOB (it doesn't matter you are not selecting it) then you get the error.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not true. In fact my view uses 10 remote tables. Some of them have CLOB and it worked. Today I tried to add new join and it happened.

Comment: Can you create the view on the remote database and then call that view over the database link? That change works for me on 19c, for a simple query and view. (Although I'm not sure *why* it works.)

Comment: Check the explain plan.   When running as a query the join is happening remotely.  When in the view it is trying to pull both tables across the DB link and then do the join (which doesn't work as you cannot pull CLOBs across DB link.
As to why it chooses one execution plan for a query and a different one for view I don't know (bug) but you could either create view on remote database or add `/*+ driving_site(a) */` hint to query to try and force everything to be done remotely